# How to properly close Qt when loaded as a shared library?

Tags: qt, lua, segmentation-fault

I have some Lua bindings to Qt that work find on mac os x (Qt 4.8.0) but crash on Ubuntu linux (Qt 4.7.4). The Qt code is loaded with a dlopen and then execution is passed to Qt with app->exec().

Lua code:

```
require 'mimas' -- Load shared library mimas.so linked to Qt libs
app = mimas.Application() -- Just a wrapper around QApplication
app:exec()
-- In some callback: app:quit()
```

When Lua quits (after app:exec() returns), it does a dlclose on the 'mimas' shared library which ends up in a SIGSEGV. Backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
QList<QFactoryLoader*>::removeAll (this=0x0, _t=@0xbfffebac)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:760
760 ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h: No such file or directory.
    in ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h
(gdb) bt
#0  QList<QFactoryLoader*>::removeAll (this=0x0, _t=@0xbfffebac)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:760
#1  0x0131126c in QFactoryLoader::~QFactoryLoader (this=0x8104a48, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at plugin/qfactoryloader.cpp:208
#2  0x01311302 in QFactoryLoader::~QFactoryLoader (this=0x8104a48, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at plugin/qfactoryloader.cpp:209
#3  0x009143a8 in QGlobalStaticDeleter<QFactoryLoader>::~QGlobalStaticDeleter (
    this=0x11c3200, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1825
#4  0x001e7d2b in __cxa_finalize () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x00842a94 in __do_global_dtors_aux ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
[snip]
#13 0x0016bd28 in dlclose () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

How can I close Qt properly so that it does not end in this memory bug ?

The problem seems to be that [qt_factory_loaders()](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryloader.cpp#line208) returns NULL. I will try with Qt 4.8.0 to see if things have changed.

[EDIT] I could narrow down the problem (it is not related to Lua) and fill a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24945) to qt.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but you can explicitly tell the Qt application to exit with `app:quit()`

Comment: app:quit() is how Qt is halted and app:exec() returns. The crash happens after this step.

Answer (score 0):

Is dlclose() maybe what you want?

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlsym.3.html

```
   The function dlclose() decrements the reference count on the dynamic library
   handle handle.  If the reference count drops to zero and no other loaded
   libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is unloaded.

   The function dlclose() returns 0 on success, and nonzero on error.
```

For example:

```
#ifdef MAC_OS
    // unload library for MAC
#else //if linux
    dlclose(lib_handle);
#endif
```

Comment: As you can see from the backtrace, 'dlclose' is called by Lua as part of its lua_close operations (frame 13). The crash happens during 'dlclose'.